# SNMPv3 user entries got deleted after reboot on SNMPv3 machine

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

After reboot on our  SNMPv3 server SNMPv3 user entries get deleted from file /var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf.

It appears  on doing reboot  engineBoots is set  to 1 in /var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf randomly and  whenever engineBoot is set to 1 it erases snmpv3 user entries  from snmpd.conf file.

Firstly, I want to understand  why engineBoots vaule is randomly set to 1, As per standard snmp document , this EngineBoots should be incremented every time we do reboot or EngineTime exceeded the max value. 
Secondly, we want to figure out the correlation of engineBoots vaule setting to 1 and the deletion of usmUser entries in /var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf.

Thanks-Ravi

Answer (score 0):

It is normal behavior. Once `snmpd` is restarted, the *create user* command line will be deleted from `/var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf` for security reason and the user will be created in `usmUsertable`.